# Problem while linking a static library during compilation in MinGW, why?

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, c++17, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a simple project which uses one of my headers. I am on Windows and I am using `MinGW-W64-builds-4.3.5` Suppose the project is called `test.cpp` and I want to compile it using my header`osmanip` which requires also the linking of its created static library `libosmanip.lib`. The static library has been compiled and created in MSYS2 and then copied into Windows filesystem. If I try to compile with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -losmanip .\test.cpp
```

To search for the system headers and library path I did:

```
g++ -v test.cpp
```

and decided to put headers into `C:\MinGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++` and the static library into `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\`.

I got the following error:

```
C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
cannot find -losmanip
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried also by adding the `-L` option, linking the library path, or editing the `LIBRARY_PATH` variable ( `$Env:LIBRARY_PATH+=";C:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/"`), but it still doesn't work.

I tried to move the library into the same folder of the `test.cpp` file and compile, but again the same error occurs.

It's strange because I tried same thing on Ubuntu, MacOS, MSYS2 and Cygwin64 and it works.

Can you help, me please?

Comment: Just to sort out... The compiler needs to know the header location for _compiling_, the library location _and_ names for _linking_. The header locations (directories) are given with `-I` (capital i). The library locations (directories) are given by `-L` (capital "ell"). The libraries are given by `-l` (non-capital "ell"). At least, on *ix, I'm used to leave out the prefix "lib" as well as the suffix - like you noted in your question: `libosmanip.a` → `-losmanip`.

Comment: Sorry I wrongly said that I used `-I` for the lib path, but I was using `-L`, I've edited the question. However by adding both include and lib path with respectively `-I` and `-L` it doesn't work too.

Comment: Maybe, check how `libosmanip.lib` has been compiled. Not that you (accidentally) built it for x86 (aka. 32 bit). I'm not sure whether the compiler/linker would give a different error message or just ignore it in this case claiming not to find it (though I tend to the former)...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I compiled it using `MSYS2 MinGW x64`

Comment: My last stupid idea... Try `g++ -std=c++17 .\test.cpp -losmanip` (instead of `g++ -std=c++17 -losmanip .\test.cpp`). I somehow remember roughly that the order of libraries in command line was important somehow (when I still was making daily business on *ix OSes). I found: [Link order of libraries](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_18.html)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It doesn't work again :(

Comment: Here and there it is stated that static libraries should have the suffix `.a` (in MinGW), maybe, to emphasize that they are just object file archives, i.e. created with `ar`. I also read that MinGW supports `.lib` as well but on Windows, a `.lib` file can be a static library, or the counter-part of the `.dll` which is needed for linking the `.dll`. So, such a `.lib` could be either or... (You need a tool to find out what it really is, or if you have both, the smaller one is usually for the `.dll` as it contains only the trampoline symbols but not the full code). ;-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat same errors persist. I think that in Windows the suffix for static libraries is .lib

Comment: _I think that in Windows the suffix for static libraries is .lib_ That's not the complete truth: [DLL and LIB files - what and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913744/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thanks, didn't know. However the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the issue. The problem was related to the fact the the suffix of my library was `.lib`. By changing it in `.a` and rebuilding the library passing the correct static library name to the `ar` command the problem disappeared.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat i rebuilded the library specifying that the suffix of the static library must be the correct one when creating it with `ar` command. I edited the answer.

Comment: MinGW is an attempt to somehow mix the Windows and *ix worlds borrowing from both. That makes not-quite-easy things even more confusing. That said, I must admit that I'm doing daily business on Windows but won't like to miss the git (based on MinGW64) with git-bash and other stuff (which looks and feels like on Linux)... ;-)